# How to Listen to XMLHttpRequests - Browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

My Script

```
var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener('load', function() {
        //console.log(this.responseURL);        
        if(this.responseURL == "https://get.example.com/dashboard/summary")
        {
            // Run the function
            funMain();
        }
    });
    origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};

function funMain() {
    // My codes
}
```

This is my script and it's working as expected. 
What this does is, this listen to XMLHttpRequests and when an XMLHttpRequest is made to 'https://get.example.com/dashboard/summary', it calls `funMain` function. Since this is an event, this is not a one time event. This can be happened multiple times. This XMLHttpRequest is made by https://example.com/dashboard webpage.

Process: If an XMLHttpRequest is made to 'https://get.example.com/dashboard/summary' by https://example.com/dashboard webpage, then call `funMain` function.

So now, I want to build an extension using this working script.
This is what I have tried so far...

Content Script

```
function funMain() {
    // My codes
}
```

Note: I know that I have to use browser.runtime.sendMessage() to communicate between background script and content script. But at the moment, I'm trying to get the event function (in the Background Script) working.

Background Script

```
console.log("Msg 01 - Background script is running.");
var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log("Msg 02 - " + this.responseURL);        
        if(this.responseURL == "https://get.example.com/dashboard/summary")
        {
            // Run the function
            // funMain();
            console.log("Msg 03 - Hello! I am working as expected.");
        }
    });
    origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Beastify",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "des",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/beasts-48.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],

  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://*.example.com/dashboard"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content-script.js"
        ]
    }],

    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

The problem is, the event does not work as expected. Therefore, funMain cannot be called. When I inspect the background page, I can only see Msg 01. I cannot see Msg 02 or Msg 03.

Output: background.js

```
Msg 01 - Background script is running.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page which is not related to the web page. In this case you don't need it at all. Use a **content script** and put that hook code in a script element as shown in [this answer](/a/9517879) so you'll override XHR in page context.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the actual situation. Here are some ideas that you can work on.

It is better to use standard JavaScript [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) instead of using`XMLHttpRequest.prototype`.

Content script and browser have different scope and for security do not interact directly.

You can

- Have XHR in the content script and use
  [webRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest)
  API in the background script to listen to HTTP requests
- Use [runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) from content script to background script to run the XHR in the background script

Then from background script

- Use
  [tabs.sendMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage) to send message to contentscript
- Use [tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) to directly run scripts in the content scope or initiate functions in the content script